# Strange Behavior using GestureDetectorCompat

Tags: android, using

I have a DoubleTapButton class that is having a strange problem.

The button is defined in the main_activity.xml file including the onClick, MainActivity.DoStuff.

The problem is that when the button is clicked, the button calls MainActivity.DoStuff BEFORE the GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener knows that a single or double click was done.

My DoubleTapButton uses setTag() to sets the buttons tag, and the doStuff method reads the tags. The tags are getting set correctly, but not until AFTER the doStuff method has been called. Too late to be of use.

I think I'm missing a step here, but I've been scrambling this code for days now, and can't seem to get it to work right.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<kenz.a.testbutton.DoubleTapButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Do Stuff"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:onClick="doStuff"/>
```

**Class DoubleTapButton**

```
package kenz.a.testbutton;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton;
import androidx.core.view.GestureDetectorCompat;

public class DoubleTapButton
   extends AppCompatButton
   implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
              GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {

private String TAG = "KENZ DoubleTapButton";
private GestureDetectorCompat myDetector;

public DoubleTapButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    myDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(context,this);
    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return myDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onSingleTapConfirmed: Setting View Tag("+getId()+") Single");
    setTag(getId(),"Single");
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onDoubleTap: Setting View Tag("+getId()+") Double");
    setTag(getId(),"Double");
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
}
@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
}
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    return false;
}
@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
}
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    return false;
 }
}
```

**class MainActivity**

```
package kenz.a.testbutton;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String TAG = "Kenz MainActivity";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void doStuff(View view) {
    String s;
    if(view.getTag(view.getId())==null)s="Null";
    else s = view.getTag(view.getId()).toString();
    Log.d(TAG, "doStuff: "+view.getTag(view.getId()));
    Toast.makeText(this,s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
 }
```

---

### LogCat Output

```
07-25 23:16:15.154 26047-26047/kenz.a.testbutton D/Kenz MainActivity: doStuff: null
07-25 23:16:15.334 26047-26047/kenz.a.testbutton D/KENZ DoubleTapButton: onSingleTapConfirmed: Setting View Tag(-1) Single
07-25 23:16:21.450 26047-26047/kenz.a.testbutton D/Kenz MainActivity: doStuff: Single
07-25 23:16:21.580 26047-26047/kenz.a.testbutton D/KENZ DoubleTapButton: onDoubleTap: Setting View Tag(-1) Double
07-25 23:16:25.074 26047-26047/kenz.a.testbutton D/Kenz MainActivity: doStuff: Double
07-25 23:16:25.204 26047-26047/kenz.a.testbutton D/KENZ DoubleTapButton: onDoubleTap: Setting View Tag(-1) Double
07-25 23:16:27.436 26047-26047/kenz.a.testbutton D/Kenz MainActivity: doStuff: Double
07-25 23:16:27.646 26047-26047/kenz.a.testbutton D/KENZ DoubleTapButton: onSingleTapConfirmed: Setting View Tag(-1) Single
```

It Appears that the onClick calls the MainActivity.doStuff(View view) BEFORE the GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener knows that a single or double click was done. I think I'm missing a step here, but I've been scrambling this code for days now, and can't seem to get it to work right.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Used a LongPress instead of a double click and removed the DoubleClick handlers. Works as required. The MainActivity.doStuff now gets the call with the "Long" or "Single" in the tag.

I use it on a zoom, single click to step zoom, long to restore normal.

> LongButton

```
enter code here
package kenz.a.testbutton;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.GestureDetector;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;

    import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton;
    import androidx.core.view.GestureDetectorCompat;

public class LongButton
    extends AppCompatButton
    implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {

private String TAG = "KENZ LongButton";
private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;
Long dtime = System.currentTimeMillis();

public LongButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(context,this);
    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
}
@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
}
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    Long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if(curTime-dtime < 200) setTag(getId(),"Double Click");
    else {
        dtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        setTag(getId(), "Single Click");
    }
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    return false;
}
@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onLongPress: Setting View Tag("+getId()+") Long");
    setTag(getId(),"Long Click");
}
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    return false;
}

}
```